# drupal 7 sql syntax

Tags: sql, drupal

i'm trying to get a results set that displays 2 columns from 2 different tables, grouping by one column and summing the other.

this sql works in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT SUM(field_count_value), field_region_value
FROM field_data_field_count, field_data_field_region
WHERE field_data_field_count.entity_id = field_data_field_region.entity_id
GROUP BY field_data_field_region.field_region_value
ORDER BY field_count_value DESC
```

displaying roughly what i need::

```
-----------------
COUNT    REGION
-----------------
4000     S
600      E
-----------------
```

but when i convert it to drupal 7 sql query syntax:

```
$nodes = db_query("SELECT SUM(field_count_value), field_region_value
FROM field_data_field_count, field_data_field_region
WHERE field_data_field_count.entity_id = field_data_field_region.entity_id
GROUP BY field_data_field_region.field_region_value
ORDER BY field_count_value DESC");

foreach ($nodes as $record) {
  echo $record->field_region_value . $record->field_count_value; 
  }
```

i can only get the group by column to display:

```
-----------------
REGION
-----------------
S
E
-----------------
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. i've consulted the official d7 docs to get this far -- not very many examples to work from there.

Comment: For such queries you should use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do

```
$nodes = db_query("SELECT SUM(field_count_value) AS field_count_value, field_region_value
FROM field_data_field_count, field_data_field_region
WHERE field_data_field_count.entity_id = field_data_field_region.entity_id
GROUP BY field_data_field_region.field_region_value
ORDER BY field_count_value DESC");
```

Otherwise the first column is called "SUM(field_count_value)"

Comment: that nailed it, andreas -- can't thank you enough. wish i would have posted here hours ago!